# Горизонтальное меню при первой загрузке страницы грузится вертикально вместо горизонтального

Tags: css

Есть менюшка, свёрстанная флоатовым списком

```
#menu ul {padding: 0;list-style: none;margin: 0 0 0 35px;}
#menu ul li {width: 108px;height: 41px;float: left;margin: 0 8px 0 0;}
```

при первой прогрузке страницы проявляется такая вот ситуация
http://i3.5cm.ru/c/ueTx.png
при перезагрузке страницы проявляется такая ситуация (какая и должна быть)
http://i2.5cm.ru/c/kmCW.png

никак не могу понять, почему так происходит. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Зачем писать «#menu ul li» если можно просто «#menu li»?

Comment: Увидев дизайн ... нервно пошел покурить ...
P.S. js не навешен на меню?

Comment: Ситуация похожа на то, что у элементов списка не срабатывает float:left. Никакие стили не перекрывают это? А на самом деле причин может быть много и по двум скринам разве что можно поиграть в битву экстрасенсов.

Comment: дизайн не мой, что дали - то сверстал.
ок, поищу перекрывающие стили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое что я бы поменял в вашем меню:

`<a href="#"><li></li></a>`

меняем на

`<li><a href="#"></a></li>`

и чтобы не возник вопрос про ссылки, пропишите стиль

```
#menu a{
       display: block;
       width: 108px;
       height: 41px;
}
```

Comment: при такой вёрстке пустой ли перестаёт быть кликабельным.

Comment: я немного не успел) как переделаете, дайте знать. если не поможет буду дальше смотреть.

Comment: хм, и правда! всё стало хорошо грузиться! по крайней мере пока..)
Я ещё начинающий, что поделать :) Спасибо!

Comment: не за что. успехов вам. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов много, это может быть связано, как с кэшем, так и очень (очень), большим .Css взаимно исключающими правилами так же это может быть какой-то javascript, можно ссылку на сайт?

Comment: к сожалению, нельзя, он на локальном компе, возможности выложить на хост нету. файл css небольшой(всего 6 кб). яваскрипты пока что вообще никакие не подключены. взаимоисключающих правил не нашёл, но поищу ещё...но что-то странное, если бы были исключающие правила - не было бы после перезагрузки нормальной картинки, разве не так?

Comment: а, нет, нашёл возможность.
http://garfil1.bget.ru/